# Transitive LUB?

Tags: scala, shapeless

What needs to be changed in this snippet that it compiles?

```
import shapeless._
import LUBConstraint._
import ops.hlist.Prepend

class Foo[L <: HList: <<:[Int]#λ](val l: L) {
  def ++[H <: HList: <<:[Int]#λ](h: H)(implicit prepend: Prepend[L, H]) = {
    new Foo(l ::: h)
  }
}
```

Currently:

```
could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type shapeless.LUBConstraint[prepend.Out,Int]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Good question ... you were very close :-)

The problem is that, even though it's obvious to us, the Scala compiler isn't able to infer that the concatenation of two `HLists` of `Int` elements is an `HList` of `Int` elements. We can help it by pulling out the type of the concatenation into a type variable (`Out`, note the use of the `Prepend.Aux` type alias to constrain this new type variable) and then asking it to prove directly that `Out` has the required property (by requiring evidence of the shape of `Out`),

```
import shapeless._
import ops.hlist.Prepend
import LUBConstraint._

class Foo[L <: HList: <<:[Int]#λ](val l: L) {
  def ++[H <: HList: <<:[Int]#λ, Out <: HList](h: H)
    (implicit prepend: Prepend.Aux[L, H, Out], ev: LUBConstraint[Out, Int]) = {
      new Foo(l ::: h)
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot get this to run, Scala can't find the necessary Prepend: https://scalafiddle.io/sf/S23uHc5/0

Comment: That's the trouble with SO ... answers go stale :-(

I've updated it for the present tense.

Comment: Thanks a lot Miles! That was a missing piece in my Shapeless puzzle :D